# Routing and Ninject gives 404

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms, ninject

I'm trying to setup routing in my web application.

It doesn't seem to work with Ninject however. If I comment all the Ninject in my Global.asax, the route works like a charm.

With Ninject in the file, I just get a 404 "The resource cannot be found" when trying to open the route page.

Heres what is in my Global.asax code:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpApplication" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Infrastructure.Storage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Ninject" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Ninject.Modules" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 }

 void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //  Code that runs on application shutdown

 }

 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

 }

 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Code that runs when a new session is started

 }

 void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Code that runs when a session ends. 
     // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
     // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
     // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

 }

 protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
 {
     IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SiteModule());
     return kernel;
 }

 public class SiteModule : NinjectModule
 {
     public override void Load()
     {
         //Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogger>().InSingletonScope();
         //Bind<IAuthentication>().To<Authentication>();
         Bind<ISession>().To<LinqToSqlSession>();
         Bind<IReadOnlySession>().To<LinqToSqlReadOnlySession>();
         //Bind<IReporting>().To<LinqToSqlReporting>();
     }
 }

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
     routes.MapPageRoute("City", "Cities/{id}", "~/test2.aspx");
 }

 </script>
```

Anyone have an idea for what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the NinjectHttpApplication class for your asax, you need to change the way the applicationStart & applicationEnd are called.

What's happening is .net automatically wires the methods above to the corresponding events. Because the NinjectHttpApplication already handles the Application_Start, your method won't get called, hence your routes are not registered. You need change that method to

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```